# Distinct topologies giving same topologies

Tags: topological-groups, profinite-groups

We have profinite group $C_p^{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is infinite countable cartesian product of finite cyclic group of prime order $p$. I understand this part that "The profinite group $C_p^{\mathbb{Z}}$ has $2^{2^{\mathcal{N}_0}}$ subgroups of index p; but only countably many open subgroups." But it goes on to say which I do not understand that is "This group therefore has many distinct topologies, but the resulting topological groups are all isomorphic."
I was going through http://www.ehu.eus/emsweekend/ficheros/DSEGAL.pdf on page 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me either...

Comment: I am no expert, but I think it means that there are many ways of viewing $C_p^{\Bbb{Z}}$ as an inverse limit of finite groups and these lead to distinct topologies (i.e., different sets of open sets), but the topologies are  homeomorphic via a group isomorphism (which presumably works by permuting the factors of the group).

Comment: @RobArthan It makes sense.